# Ruby/Rails - delayed_job Rails.env is "development" when I'm in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm running Ruby 1.9.2/Rails 3.0.9.

I am using the [collective idea fork of delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

I am starting delayed_job like so:
`RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`

It pulls jobs from my production database.

However, when processing them, the Rails.env is evaluating as "development".
I am doing some image uploading (using paperclip), and they are going to my "development" directory on my CDN host.

Further evidence:

If I use an `if` statement in the code that delayed_job runs, Rails.env evaluates to "development".

That is,

```
x = 1  
if Rails.env == "production"
  x = 2
end
```

x still equals 1

```
x = 1  
if Rails.env == "development"
  x = 2
end
```

x now equals 2.

Why does Rails.env == "development"?
How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is in your script/delayed_job file?

Comment: I've never touched it:

`require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))`  
`require 'delayed/command'`  
`Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have "development" hard coded somewhere around your Paperclip configuration. I would do a full source code search and see if that's the case.

Comment: I don't think so.  The paperclip path is set via a :rails_env variable.  I'm going to edit my original post with another example/more evidence.

Comment: Delayed job wouldn't just inject "development" into your code. It's obviously hard coded somewhere in your code base. Little mistakes can cause huge headaches. Just do a full source code search and see if this is the case.

Comment: LoL, Ugh, I had this beautiful little line of code in a method:

`function_call if Rails.env = "development"`

I feel dumb and angry now.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It happens to be the best of us.